# What is the current gas price to deploy an ethereum contract? How much will I have to pay?

Tags: blockchain, transactions, gas

I couldn't find anywhere to get this data. With ETH 2.0, does anyone know the price?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on 3 things, namely:

- Network activity (the higher the activity, the higher the gas fee).
- ETH/USD price.
- The size of the contract/s you want to deploy.